# Flexible joint methods for upper limb exoskeleton robot need?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on project of building a upper limb exoskeleton robot with 4 dof. In order to get human like motion, it need to catch the axis offset at human anatomy in to my robot. I though that it may can get from some flexible coupling, but still not sure. Any of u have idea of how to get flexible motion into robot in order to get human like motion. do you know any machine components which are available to generate flexible motion in robotic joints? it is better that if u can provide some useful links to search for details.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55407/flexible-joint-methods-for-upper-limb-exoskeleton-robot-need-!!/) by [Pamuditha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4219/pamuditha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Pamuditha

Firstly you will need to re-examine your DOF requirement. The Human arm has 6 DOF (x, y, z and roll pitch yaw) which are achieved in 7 joints (which means one of the joints is redundant). There is a paper from 2006 by Perry and Rosen a link to the website explaining their research is available here:

[here](http://bionics.soe.ucsc.edu/research/exoskeleton_device_3.html)

Hopes this helps start you on your project.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1